# Доп. поля для laravel с зависимостью от выбранной категории

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-8

Подскажите, как реализовать подобное. Есть модель Song (аналог классическому Post). В неё добавляется поле для основного текста песни. Если песня иностранная (какой-то тумблер должен быть), то должно появляться поле для перевода этой песни. Как реализовать подобное на Laravel? Должны ли доп. поля песни быть созданы сразу в БД или это делается как-то динамически? Может быть, нужно создавать разные модели?

Comment: "какой-то тумблер должен быть" – это чисто js. В Laravel в любом случае на обработку все поля пойдут. Доп.поля могут быть сразу все, а могут быть вынесены в отдельную таблицу (`song_fields` – `id`, `field_name` или `field_id` + справочник типов полей, `field_value`).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а как правильнее, выводить в отдельную таблицу или или сразу добавлять в общую?

Comment: Зависит от количества полей. Если вы собрались на все языки переводить песни, то лучше отдельную таблицу (и там, возможно, не fields уже, а `song_translations` - `song_id`, `language_id`, `content`). Если только основной язык и язык перевода, то, делить на таблицы особо и не стоит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По любому должны быть доп. поля в базе, если вы хотите в дальнейшем реализовать какой-то адекватный поиск по тексту. А делать это в отдельной таблице или в той же зависит от количества языков. Если языков только два (оригинал и перевод на русский), делайте в одной. Если более - то лучше отдельная таблица.

Для первого варианта можно например добивать поля: lang, text, text_ru

Если lang = 'rus' выводите только поле text, а если lang = 'eng', то выводите оба поля text и text_ru.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал через две таблицы
`songs`, `songs_translates`

Должен быть обязатеельный язык и дополнительные
Дополнительные - на клиенте через js
А на сервере - сохраняете в зависимости от того, что вам пришло

Такое решение даст вам возможность без проблем добавлять различные языки в будующем времени